# How to implement an admin approval system for posting blogs in node.js and express application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have made a **Blog app** using **Node.js, Express, and MongoDB**. The user has to sign in to create a blog and post it on the site. But, now I want to design a system so that an *admin has to approve the user's post* before actually publishing that particular blog on the site.

I want to create an admin panel where he/she can see all the user's posts with username and userid. And, I want an *approval button* or such thing on every post, so that only after admin approves the user's post, it is published on the actual site.

Please suggest me the solution to achieve this.

PS: I do not know how to create the admin panel at all.

Comment: Hey. Your question is a bit to broad to be answered on stackoverflow. In general you want to be a able to mark users as admins. Then create routes that are only accessible to admin users. Your blogposts must be extended by an "approved" flag (boolean field). Create a site that lists all unapproved blog posts and has the ability to mark them approved. On your public site filter the blog posts to just show approved posts.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you are new in Node.js. So you should know some basic knowledge like the basic API call, how to render a page, creating a Model and also Save, Update And Delete.

If you know about Model, View, Controller, and Routes. Then you can understand the following methodology.

First of all, the Admin Panel is a page like other pages that can only access Admin. For this, you can make a field in the USER model name isAdmin which probably by default False. If isAdmin == True then you can render those Admin Page. You can put a button on the home page which can only show when isAdmin == True. After clicking the button it will take you to that **Admin** page.

Then, you have to make a field named isApproved in the POST model which also by default False.

In Admin Page you can make a button **Approve Post** with other information when you click on that button **isApproved** field of the post will become True.

Finally, A post will show when isApproved == True. You can comment for further solution.

Comment: Can u elaborate more.

Comment: Share any article related to this

Comment: @user16102215 sorry I don't have any relevant paper. I have said that based on experience.